# Calculate form inputs and display on screen

Tags: jquery

I've two date fields which i already calculate as i need the time. In addition to these i have 6 drop downs which hold numeric values.

When the user selects any of these fields i want the total to be calculated/updated onscreen similar to a shopping cart.
I started with something like this but i can't get the bloody thing to work obviously my logic is at fault. I realise it's wrong but i don't know how to fix it.

```
$(function(){
$('a#calc').click(function(){
var p = $('select#TRDO').val();
var q = $('select#AnnualLeave').val();
var r = $('select#PersonalLeave').val();
var s = $('select#WorkFromHome').val();
var t = $('select#TOIL').val();
var tot = (q+p+r+s+t);
$('input#total').val(tot);
});
```

});

I just need help in doing the first one then i'll be right to go it on my own.

Thanks it's been a very frustrating day...

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use `parseInt` to do a nummeric addition:

```
$(function(){
  $('a#calc').click(function(){
     var p = parseInt($('select#TRDO').val(), 10);
     var q = parseInt($('select#AnnualLeave').val(), 10);
     var r = parseInt($('select#PersonalLeave').val(), 10);
     var s = parseInt($('select#WorkFromHome').val(), 10);
     var t = parseInt($('select#TOIL').val(), 10);
     var tot = (q+p+r+s+t);
     $('input#total').val(tot);
  });
});
```

Without `parseInt()` the plus operator (`+`) will concat strings instead of adding their numeric values.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Villegas Alvarado Is there something i'm missing in getting this tally / calculate. <input name="total" class="formfieldct4" id="total" /> <a id="calc" href="#">HERE</a>

Comment: No, you're not missing anything. If the problem persists, could you upload your code to jsfiddle.net, and give me the url to review it?

Comment: What i'm after is for the field to update as the user selects any item.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

add a class to all your inputs you want to total up and use parseInt...Oh and you most likely don't want to use .click you probably want .change

```
<input class="inputsToSum" value="4"/>

var runningTotal = 0;
$(".inputsToSum").change(function() {
    runningTotal += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
});
$('input#total').val(runningTotal);
```

Comment: I tried using this but it kept asking me for tot. It's not calculating onchange also...Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
$('a #calc').click(function(){
var p = $('#TRDO option:selected').val();
var q = $('#AnnualLeave option:selected').val();
var r = $('#PersonalLeave option:selected').val();
var s = $('#WorkFromHome option:selected').val();
var t = $('#TOIL option:selected').val();
var tot = (parseInt(q)+parseInt(p)+parseInt(r)+parseInt(s)+parseInt(t));
$('input #total').val(tot);
});
```

UPDATE

this code works when click calculate

```
$(function() {
     $('a #calc').click(function(){

        var p = parseFloat($('select[name=TRDO] option:selected').val());
        var q = parseFloat($('select[name=AnnualLeave] option:selected').val());
        var r = parseFloat($('select[name=PersonalLeave] option:selected').val());
        var s = parseFloat($('select[name=WorkFromHome] option:selected').val());
        var t = parseFloat($('select[name=TOIL] option:selected').val());

        var tot = (q + p + r + s + t);
         $('input#total').val(tot);

    });
});
```

Comment: i tried to use your sample but it won't compute it gives NaN. 

`<input name="total" class="formfieldct4" id="total" /> <a id="calc" href="#">HERE</a>` This is how i initialise the function.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you just parse it into integer or float...

```
$(function(){
$('a#calc').click(function(){
var p = $('select#TRDO').val();
var q = $('select#AnnualLeave').val();
var r = $('select#PersonalLeave').val();
var s = $('select#WorkFromHome').val();
var t = $('select#TOIL').val();
var tot = (parseInt(q)+parseInt(p)+parseInt(r)+parseInt(s)+parseInt(t));
$('input#total').val(tot);
});
});
```